# Unable to load SiteMinder host configuration object or host configuration file

Tags: windows, iis-7.5, siteminder

The application log in the event viewer shows

> Unable to load SiteMinder host configuration object or host configuration file

for Siteminder 12.51 on IIS 7.5 (64bit) OS Windows 2008 (64bit).

Answer (score 1):

When do you get the error? Is it when you're configuring the Webagent?

Anyway, verify the following.

- Verify your environment variables are set correctly, if must have references to the Webagent files, you may need to export the envvars in the webagent or policy server folder (nete_wa_env...) file.
- if the host config object you're using exists? Verify this using the
  Admin UI
- If the hostname is configured in the policy server as a trusted host
- Verify if the settings are correct in the corresponding SmHost.conf file in the webagent folder
- Verify and eliminate any duplicate or conflicting lines in your IIS config files which refer to siteminder.
- Verify the host config object and the agent config object settings.

Answer (score 0):

make sure WebAgent.conf is pointing to the correct SmHost.conf and SmHost.conf has the correct HostConfigObject defined (with the exact case that is used in the Policy Store).

If the HCO in the Policy Store is named "DefaultHostSettings" and SmHost.conf contains `HostConfigObject=defaulthostsettings` you will get this type of error.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-registering the web agent with the policy server using the `smreghost` command.